Why isn't c++ letting me include a header file?
I am trying to use SDL2 with C++, but have spent months trying to get it working.
at the top of my script, I have:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
in my include path, I have:
"${workspaceFolder}/include"
and my file structure is:
Project\include\SDL2
the sdl2 header files are in the SDL2 folder.
when running, I get this error for whatever reason:

fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include 
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~


c_cpp_properties.json only affects hints in the editor, not the actual compilation. You want to add -Iinclude to your tasks.json if you're using one.

I would recommend to use of CMake (with some package manager) and then configure VScode to use CMake. This way you r project will not be bounded to specific IDE.


c_cpp_properties.json only affects hints in the editor, not the actual compilation. You want to add -Iinclude to your tasks.json if you're using one.

–
HolyBlackCat
